# how to make layout false for devise sign in action,and how to make sign up to take different layout for devise sign up in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, layout, devise, signing

i don't want to have layout for devise sign_up. by default it is taking application layout. and i want to have separate layout for devise sign_in action. how can i configure this? what are the sequence of configuration steps for these?

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
layout : custom_layout
end


class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  layout : false
end
```

i genearated the devise controllers and overridden like the above. still its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code in your `application_controller`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  layout :layout_by_resource

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user && action_name == 'new'
      "your_custom_layout"
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

More Info [***Here***](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts)